# Keep just one legend in my plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset like this:

```
a <- letters[1:10]
b <- c(4.04,5.12,9.69,8.77,8.39,5.77,5.62,1.85,4.58,5.00)
c <- c(14.05,5.71,11.11,9.77,9.06,7.33,6.24,2.28,7.33,5.17)
d <- c("e","f","c","d","a","e","e","b","f","b")
df <-data.frame(a,b,c,d)
```

I made this plot:

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x= b, y= c, shape=d, color = d)) +
geom_point() + 
geom_text(aes(label=a), size=3.2, hjust = 0.5, vjust = 1.5)
```

And I got this:

[image]

How can I remove the letter "a" behind each shape in the legend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that the `geom_text` layer is adding to the legend. Here are some examples to show you what is happening:

If you just call the `ggplot` with the `geom_point` layer, you get the correct legend:

```
p <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = b, y = c, shape = d, color = d))
p + geom_point()
```

[image]

Try calling it with just the `geom_text` layer and you'll see the legend uses 'a'

```
p + geom_text(aes(label = a), size = 3.2, hjust = 0.5, vjust = 1.5)
```

[image]

Pass `show.legend = FALSE` to prevent the `geom_text` layer from adding to the legend:

```
p + geom_point() +
  geom_text(aes(label = a), size = 3.2, hjust = 0.5, vjust = 1.5, show.legend = FALSE)
```

[image]